# How to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> from one Activity to a Fragment?

Tags: java, android

How i can pass Array List **from one Activity to a `Fragment`** my `ArrayList` is shown as follows.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle.putSerializable("hashmap",mMap);
`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 passing data between activities and pasing data from activity to fragment have different approaches

Comment: `fragmentInstance.pass(arrayList);`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Is a different question please remove the flag

Comment: My bad. I read it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to send your list

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
MyFragment mFrag = new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("LIST", (Serializable) mapArrayList);
mFrag.setArguments(args);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(container_id, mFrag).commit();
```

and get your list inside your fragment like this

```
Bundle myBundle=getArguments();
if(myBundle!=null){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapArrayList= myBundle.getSerializable("LIST");
 }
```

Comment: Incompatible types Required java.util.ArrayList Found java.io.Serializable

Comment: Sure it is: error: incompatible types: Serializable cannot be converted to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Answer (score 1):

1. `HashMap<String, String>` can be stored in `Bundle`:

   ```
   private Bundle transformMapToBundle(HashMap<String, String> map){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
           bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       return bundle;
   }
   ```
2. Making above transformation from each `map` in your `List` to the correspondent `bundle` (not the same) you can represent `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` as a
   `ArrayList<Bundle>`

   ```
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMaps;

   ArrayList<Bundle> listOfBundle = new ArrayList<>(listOfMaps.size());
   for (HashMap<String, String> map : listOfMaps)
       listOfBundle.add(transformMapToBundle(map));
   ```
3. `Bundle` implements `Parcelable` therefore you may use
   `putParcelableArrayList`.

   ```
   Bundle bundleEnveloping = new Bundle();
   bundleEnveloping.putParcelableArrayList(listOfBundle);

   MyFragment mFrag = new MyFragment();
   mFrag.setArguments(bundleEnveloping);
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, mFrag).commit();
   ```

So, it may looks like a sending of `List<Bundle>` in the "enveloping" `Bundle`if you just want to start a `Fragment` with your `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` in it's `arguments`.

P.S. With a little modification of above code you can send any

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Parcelable>>
```

by this way.